# Adding an index to a list of a lists in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists like this:-

```
x=[['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H']]
```

I am trying to add an index to the list like this:-

```
y=[[0,'A','B','C','D'],[1,'E','F','G','H']]
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
y = [[i]+a for i,a in enumerate(x)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#enumerate) and [`insert`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
x = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H']]
y = []

for index, li in enumerate(x):
    li_copy = li[:]
    li_copy.insert(0, index)
    y.append(li_copy)

print(y)
#  [[0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]
```

Or if you don't mind overwriting `x`:

```
x = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H']]

for index, li in enumerate(x):
    li.insert(0, index)  

print(x)
#  [[0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]
```

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace. Is there a way to make sure x is not changed. The above suggestion is changing x as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution works perfectly by initiating y=[] instead of y=x[:]

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a simple function that achieves this try the following:

```
def add_index(itemList):
    i = 0
    setOfLists = []
    for x in itemList:
       set_of_lists.append([i] + x) 
       i +=1
    return setOfLists
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use [`collections.deqeue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) for this:

```
from collections import deque

lst = [['A','B','C','D'],['E','F','G','H']]

result = []
for i, l in enumerate(lst):
    q = deque(l)
    q.appendleft(i)
    result.append(list(q))

print(result)
```

Which Outputs:

```
[[0, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], [1, 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']]
```